# custom event in JQuery not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

My custom event is very basic, I'm trying to see a console.log message when I click in a input (is a checkbox) inside a div. For any reason my event handler (by using .on) is never fired. Any idea?

```
// define custom event
$.event.special.selectnetwork = {
  eventType : 'selectnetwork',
  setup: function(data, namespaces) {
   $(this).find('input').bind('change', $.event.special.selectnetwork.handler); 
  },
  teardown: function(namespaces) {

  },
  handler: function(event) {
    event.type = 'selectnetwork';
    console.log('im here'); // I reach this poing
    return $.event.dispatch.apply(this, arguments); // Something wrong?
  }
};

// test the custom event
$('div#mydiv').on('selectnetwork', function(event) {
    console.log('selected'); // never is printed
});
```

Comment: For the sake of being completely honest (it's probably a typo), that syntax error in your `.log()` will stop your script working.

Comment: ouch, sorry, I fixed the type, but the problem persist. Seems that was an error putting the code here. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in your .log() that's probably a typo, but it'll stop your script. Other than that, supposedlly custom events need to be bound with .bind() instead of .on()

Comment: yes, sorry!, my bad, putting the code here seems that I made a mistake. The log is fine now, but the problem persist. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but because events bubble up to their parents, the following will accomplish what I believe your example intends to do.

```
$('div#mydiv').on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('selected');
});
```

Comment: well.....good point, that work. At least I can make sure that a block of the code is fine. Thanks!